# How to edit EXIF populated content type fields in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, edit, exif

I am using Drupal 7. I have created a content type IMAGE with keywords, caption, headline, category populated by EXIF and I also autogenerate the label. All I have to do is select a local image and hit save and everything I need is populated from the image metadata - all good so far.

The only problem is that I cannot edit the EXIF populated fields. If  I want to move an image from one category (taxonomy) to another or notice a typo in the caption the only way I can make corrections is to delete the image, correct the text locally and reupload the image - when I select EDIT having found the content the default edit page does not show the field populated by EXIF. If I change them on the content type to a text or taxonomy field I can edit them, but I can't do that each time I want to edit a field.

I have searched but found nothing to help. Alternatively I have considered duplicating the EXIF populated fields on the IMAGE content type amd populating them using tokens from the EXIF populated fields and using those to drive my display views etc. I should then be able to edit them but it is not a very elegant solutions. I am not sure that will work after initially trying it.

I also have an issue that I need a multi-valued field other than keywords that I can use for the category/gallery (and there isn't one in the standard it seems). That will probably be a separate question when I have solved the editing problem.

I also tried using EditableViews modules which looked promising but it would still not let me edit the fields although it did display them.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the structure of your content type. Is there an image in it? Why can't you edit the node? If you want to change the taxonomy, just change it. I really don't understand the problem.

Comment: It is a content type that contains: an Image, Caption, Headline, Image-Reference and Gallery fields as well as the Title. The gallery field is so that I can select images by gallery for display views/slideshows. That all works fine. Offline, I maintain that data in IPTC data with the master image. When I upload I automatically populate the content type fields using EXIF to read the IPTC data and copy  it into the content type fields. Gallery is  a taxonomy reference field. They all populate properly. and the data is in the database

Comment: When I select an instance of the Image content type for edit it does not show me the fields that are filled in by EXIF module to allow me to edit them. I can do it if, after I have uploaded with EXIF, I change the field widget on the content type to, say, an autocomplete taxonomy field, I can then edit that field (but it will not automatically populate (EXIF) on upload). I can switch back in forth but that is extremely inconvenient.